# Flash inside Android WebView — How do I set fullscreen automatically?

Tags: android, flash, webview, fullscreen

I am loading Flash SWFs into an Android WebView.

I want the SWF to be instantly fullscreen and focused.

The class name that handles flash is `com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface`. Watching the log, when I fullscreen the flash manually, it calls `com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface.toggleFullScreen()`.

The first part of my question is: How can I call that method manually for my Flash SWF?

Note that with a webview with a flash embedded, the only way I seem to be able to fullscreen it properly (to have Flash's `surfaceview` fullscreen instead of the flash being displayed over top of the `webview view`) is by touching the screen with two fingers until an interface pops up at the top of the screen, and doesn't happen reliably.

For focus, inside my webview class I call:

```
@Override 
protected boolean drawChild (Canvas canvas, View child, long drawingTime) {

    if (child.getClass().getName().equals("com.adobe.flashplayer.FlashPaintSurface")) {
        child.requestFocus();
    }
    return super.drawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
}
```

This doesn't set the focus as I thought it would. Although I assume, if fullscreened properly, the FlashPaintSurface should give itself focus. But if the first part is not doable, I would wonder at least to not have to give focus to the SWF by clicking on it on startup.

Please note I am doing this dynamically, not calling my own SWFs that I make myself, so I cannot solve this with Actionscript.

Comment: ive found the solution to the focus problem was to add onload="document.OBJECTID.focus();" into the HTML <body> and id="OBJECTID" name="OBJECTID" into the <EMBED>, however i still cant invoke the method properly.

Comment: I am not sure this is possible, when you run a swf in a browser, you can usually only go fullscreen from a user event, like touch or click with mouse. Its for security. If the app was run in adobe air you can go fullscreen without user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I have had success this using the code on my previous solution to [Problem to load flv video in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596243/problem-to-load-flv-video-in-webview/6855609#6855609).  It may be of some help.

The embed tag looks like this:

```
<embed
 style="width:100%; height:100%"
 src="./FLVPlayer.swf?fullscreen=true&video=./expression_sad.flv"
 autoplay="true"
 quality="high"
 bgcolor="#000000"
 name="VideoPlayer"
 align="middle"
 allowScriptAccess="*"
 allowFullScreen="true"
 type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
 </embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Every Android App By Adobe uses a file **"application.xml"** -- by default as its Descriptor:

Take a look at that file before you write any code for this.
It changes every revision, but the last time I used it was to set this variable (Full_screen)..